# QField - Managing photo storage

Tags: qgis-3, qfield, photos

I'm using QField and was able to setup almost everything.
I managed to enable photos creating a table (with the "attachment" type, relative path and so forth) and building relations to my Shapefile. This all works great.

My problem is that when I take a photo from the shape's menu, I get weird behavior:

- Sometimes, the photo is stored in DCIM at root of the project in the
  phone
- Sometimes, the photo is stored in the DCIM of the file, outside the project folder and mixed with my regular phone photos
- In that second situation, the photo's name is different from the name stored in my table

Is there a way to force where the pictures taken from QField are stored?
I'm not using a external memory card, everything is stored locally on the phone.

Here are some pictures of my project:
[image: My Shapefile]

[image: My table to store the photos]

[image: The relation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case somebody else bumps into that problem:

After more research, I found that the problem is the phone itself (more precisely the cache management system).

I had basically this problem:
https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/400

The proposed link here pointed me in the right direction:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/165818/some-folders-and-files-not-showing-up-on-pc-when-connected-via-usb

After flushing my cache, I could see the DCIM folder in the Qfield directory, and the pictures were automatically moved back into it.

EDIT: After more testings, only flushing the cache didn't work, but only restarting the phone did.

A bit of a pain to flush the cache before every sync, but still a fix.
I would guess this issue wouldn't happen with a more recent phone.

EDIT2: I can reproduce systematically this problem with another Android tablet. Android 5.0.2